# a doubt in wedderburn artin theorem

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

i am doing proof of wedderburn artin theorem from T Y Lam but the fact used in proof is decomposing semisimple Ring R as FINITE direct sum of minimal left ideals, but in in definition it is said to be direct sum of a family of minimal ideals, and explaination is as 1 belongs to R so sum will be FINITE. I don't get it, i know direct sum means only finitely many non zero elements but why 1 belong to R forces only finite number of minimum ideals in decomposition of semisimple ring R. i know answer to it is very short but its just not clicking. any help or hint? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See theorem 3.4 on p. 16 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=iLwb9FWNRSwC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=decompose%20semisimple%20ring%20as%20minimal%20left%20ideals&source=bl&ots=tXdjMoLEwD&sig=sxpez7Ef6tlQAzvBU3JJ25mVPsY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7pGWU-v2O4-nyAS2xoLQCQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=decompose%20semisimple%20ring%20as%20minimal%20left%20ideals&f=false).  In short, a partition of unity picks out a sufficient finite set of minimal left ideal summands to span the ring.